# TypeError: cb is not a function at secretProvider in node.js back-end api using express-jwt

Tags: node.js, express, jwt

```
TypeError: cb is not a function
    at secretProvider
```

is the error im getting here is the index.js file where I use express and jwt to connect to Auth0

```
const express = require('express')
const bodyParser = require('body-parser')
const { expressjwt: jwt } = require("express-jwt");
const jwksRsa = require('jwks-rsa');
const envVariables = require('./env-variables.json');
const db = require('./queries')
const port = 3000
const app = express()
app.use(bodyParser.json())
app.use(
  bodyParser.urlencoded({
    extended: true,
  })
)

app.use(jwt({
  // Dynamically provide a signing key based on the kid in the header and the singing keys provided by the JWKS endpoint.
  secret: jwksRsa.expressJwtSecret({
    cache: true,
    rateLimit: true,
    jwksRequestsPerMinute: 5,
    jwksUri: `https://${envVariables.auth0Domain}/.well-known/jwks.json`,
  }),

  // Validate the audience and the issuer.
  audience: envVariables.apiIdentifier,
  issuer: `https://${envVariables.auth0Domain}/`,
  algorithms: ['RS256']
}));
app.get('/private', (req, res) => res.send('Only authenticated users can read this message.'));
app.get('/users', db.getUsers)
app.get('/users/:id', db.getUserById)
app.post('/users', db.createUser)
app.put('/users/:id', db.updateUser)
app.delete('/users/:id', db.deleteUser)

app.listen(port, () => {
  console.log(`App running on port ${port}.`)
})
```

I have no idea what to do im new to back-end, the problem might have started when i updated the dependencies, which are now different from the tutorial i used

Answer (score 1):

Just update the jwks-rsa library

```
npm update jwks-rsa
```

Ensure you have the caret symbol for that library in your package.json, like this:

```
"jwks-rsa": "^2.1.5",
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if you had found your fix since you had ask your question here. I just face the exact same issue as you.

It comes from an incompatibility between express 4.x and jwksRsa.expressJwtSecret, it seems.

I do not succeed to fix it. By had use another dependencie i order to solve the issue.

**node-oauth2-jwt-bearer** you can find the git page here : https://github.com/auth0/node-oauth2-jwt-bearer/tree/main/packages/express-oauth2-jwt-bearer

Basically with your exemple it will becomes :

```
const express = require('express')
const bodyParser = require('body-parser')
const { auth } = require("express-oauth2-jwt-bearer");
const envVariables = require('./env-variables.json');
const db = require('./queries')
const port = 3000
const app = express()
app.use(bodyParser.json())
app.use(
  bodyParser.urlencoded({
    extended: true,
  })
)

app.use(auth ({
  audience: envVariables.apiIdentifier,
  issuerBaseURL: `https://${envVariables.auth0Domain}/`,
  tokenSigningAlg: 'RS256'
}));
app.get('/private', (req, res) => res.send('Only authenticated users can read this message.'));
app.get('/users', db.getUsers)
app.get('/users/:id', db.getUserById)
app.post('/users', db.createUser)
app.put('/users/:id', db.updateUser)
app.delete('/users/:id', db.deleteUser)

app.listen(port, () => {
  console.log(`App running on port ${port}.`)
})
```

If you still have trouble you may find some help through that tutorial : https://auth0.com/docs/quickstart/backend/nodejs/interactive#configure-the-middleware

Hope it helps